# How can I keep my MacBook Air's battery cool?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, cooling

It seems that the [best advice for battery longevity](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/17369/218) on my MacBook Air is to keep the battery cool. It doesn't have powerful fans like the MacBook Pro, so I would think that overheating is even more of a problem on an Air than a Pro. What are the best ways to keep the MacBook Air cool?

Note: this isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13522/how-can-i-keep-my-macbook-pro-cool-and-avoid-fan-noise) since that question (and the answers) deals with how to prevent the fan noise.

Answer (score 3):

Apple only provides a few [recommendations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4543).

Use the computer on a hard surface:

> Using the computer on a soft surface like a couch, pillow, bed, or your lap can trap heat requiring higher fan activity. Using the computer on a hard flat surface like a table or desk allows for optimal radiation of heat.

Don't block the fans:

> Make sure the vents remain unblocked to allow your computer to perform at its best.

On the MacBook Air, the fans are located in back.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from experience, I would say that you should be cautious of **running Anti-Virus apps which actively scan your computer**. They are often resource intensive, and I've noticed that these apps can conflict with Spotlight and cause the CPU usage to skyrocket for a long period of time, which heats up the battery.

Answer (score 0):

I got an [iLap](http://raindesigninc.com/ilap.html) for my wife, and it works great.